# Can human beings be reborn as deities after living an ethical life?

Tags: gods, rebirth

I read that many Hindu traditions believe that a human being has the potential to be reborn as a deity by living an ethical life and building up good karma.

Comment: For one they can be directly promoted to become a deity or deity like. For example - The Asura King Mahãrãj Bali was bestowed with the position of Devarãj Indra by Shri Vishnu for the next manvantara i.e. Sãvarni

Answer (score 2):

> Can human beings be reborn as deities after living an ethical life?

Yes they can. If you are sattvic and follow dharma, you can be reborn as a deva (god). From the *Manusmriti*:

> [12.40](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202221.html) - **Those partaking of ‘Sattva’ reach the state of the devas (gods)**, those endowed with ‘Rajas,’ the state of humans, and those characterised by ‘Tamas,’ the state of animals; such is the threefold migratory state.

> Sacrificers, rishis (sages), **devas (gods)**, vedas, luminaries, years, Pitṛs and Sādhyas represent the second state partaking of ‘Sattva.’

Comment: So if I die and become a god after death, do I join the Hindu pantheon?

Comment: @Orionixe Yes you do